# How to add multiple cells to a row in a table in bigtable?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I've been trying so many different github project examples and read the bigtable api guide multiple times. I can't figure out why it doesn't allow me to set multiple cells in a row. In the examples shown they only have examples with one value per row.

I also used the cbt commands to see if the column families I added are in the table and they are in the table but when I used the count command I see no entries.

I've used both the mutate_rows command for the table and the commit command on the row but neither add the row.
I also do realize that the row commit command is literally just:

```
table.mutate_rows([row])
```

So, I cant seem to understand what I'm doing wrong at all.

```
import base64
import json
import ast
import datetime

from google.cloud import bigtable
from google.cloud.bigtable import column_family
from google.cloud.bigtable import row_filters


def function(event, context):

    data = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    data = ast.literal_eval(data)

    print(type(data))
    print(data)

    # Create a Cloud Bigtable client.
    client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)

    # Connect to an existing Cloud Bigtable instance.
    instance = client.instance(instance_id)

    print('opening the {} table.'.format(table_id))
    table = instance.table(table_id)

    # [START writing_rows]

    max_versions_rule = column_family.MaxVersionsGCRule(2)
    column_family_id = 'states'.encode('utf-8')
    column_families = {column_family_id: max_versions_rule}
    if not table.exists():
        table.create(column_families=column_families)
    else:
        print("Table {} already exists.".format(table_id))


    row_key = (data['serial_num'] + str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())).encode('utf-8')

    row_obj = table.row(row_key)

    for key, value in data.items():
        row_obj.set_cell(
            column_family_id, 
            str(key).encode('utf-8'), 
            str(value).encode('utf-8'), 
            timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        )

    print(row_obj)
    print(str(row_obj))
    print(row_obj.table)
    print(row_obj.row_key)

    row_obj.commit()

    '''
    table.mutate_rows([row_obj])
    '''

    print('Inserted/updated data.')

    # [END writing_rows]

    # [START creating_a_filter]

    # Create a filter to only retrieve the most recent version of the cell
    # for each column across entire row.
    row_filter = row_filters.CellsColumnLimitFilter(1)

    # [END creating_a_filter]

    # [START read_rows]

    row = table.read_row(row_key, row_filter)
    print(row)
    for key, value in data.items():
        cell_values = row.cells[column_family_id][column][0]
        print('{} = {} should be {}'.format(key, cell_values, value))

    # [END read_rows]
```

Comment: This excerpt looks a bit off:
```
    for key, value in data.items():
        cell_values = row.cells[column_family_id][column][0]
        print('{} = {} should be {}'.format(key, cell_values, value))
```
Specifically, `row.cells[column_family_id][column][0]`.  Should it be `row.cells[column_family_id][key][0]`?

Comment: Also it helps to think of this more as you're applying _mutations_ to the rows, rather than specifying a whole row in one go. Looking at the [python write example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigtable/hello/main.py#L61-L85) you could instead have all those as set_cells applying to the same row key being passed to mutate_rows.

Comment: @Dan So I can pass the entire dictionary as a value into one cell? And also even if that were the case shouldn't it still add at least one cell into the row and it should be able to create an entry based off that mutation; however, when I run the cbt count command on my database it returns 0

Comment: More so something along the following:
rows = []
for key, value in data.items():
  row_key = (data['serial_num'] + str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())).encode('utf-8')
  row = table.row(row_key)
  row.set_cell(column_family_id,
      str(key).encode('utf-8'),
      str(value).encode('utf-8'),
      timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
  rows.append(row)
table.mutate_rows(rows)

Comment: Thanks that works; I didn't think doing it that way would save it as one entry! I also misunderstood what column families were and was thinking about in a SQL way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up with

```
import base64
import json
import ast
import datetime

from google.cloud import bigtable
from google.cloud.bigtable import column_family
from google.cloud.bigtable import row_filters


def hello_pubsub(event, context):

    data = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    data = ast.literal_eval(data)

    print(type(data))
    print(data)

    # Create a Cloud Bigtable client.
    client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)

    # Connect to an existing Cloud Bigtable instance.
    instance = client.instance(instance_id)

    print('opening the {} table.'.format(table_id))
    table = instance.table(table_id)

    # [START writing_rows]

    max_versions_rule = column_family.MaxVersionsGCRule(2)
    column_family_id = 'state'
    column_families = {column_family_id: max_versions_rule}
    if not table.exists():
        table.create(column_families=column_families)
    else:
        print("Table {} already exists.".format(table_id))


    row_key = (data['serial_num'] + " " + str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())).encode('utf-8')

    rows = [] 

    for key, value in data.items():
        row = table.row(row_key)
        row.set_cell(column_family_id, 
            str(key).encode('utf-8'), 
            str(value), 
            timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        rows.append(row)


    table.mutate_rows(rows)

    print('Inserted/updated data.')

    # [END writing_rows]

    # [START creating_a_filter]

    # Create a filter to only retrieve the most recent version of the cell
    # for each column across entire row.
    row_filter = row_filters.CellsColumnLimitFilter(1)

    # [END creating_a_filter]

    # [START read_rows]

    partial_rows = table.read_row(row_key, row_filter)
    print(partial_rows.cells)
    for key, value in data.items():
        cell_value = partial_rows.cell_value(column_family_id, str(key).encode('utf-8'))
        print('{} = {} should be {}'.format(key, cell_value, value))

    # [END read_rows]
```

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!